# text analysis Python

Tags: python, text

I have a data frame with text and I would like to extract name of the beer which is always after the phrase ''Drinking a ...'. I cannot just extract 3rd and 4th word because sometimes there is some additional word like in the last line. I would like to extract whole name of a beer as one string. Did anyone worked on something similar?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to convert the string to a list, find the index  i of "drinking", the index of the name of the beer is i+2 and i+3

Comment: You can also apply regex to this class of problem, searching for a string that follows `drinking a` and comes before `by`. That said, for a solid answer here, you should try giving us what you tried, and where you got stuck! It can also be helpful to provide sample inputs in textual (rather than image) format, along with what you expect your outputs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the string to a list, find the index i of "drinking", the index of the name of the beer is i+2 and i+3

```
text = text.lower().split()
i = text.index("drinking") 
name = text[i+2] + " " + text[i+3]
```

for

```
text = "Drinking a black pale ale"
name = "black pale"
```

As suggested, you can also find the index j of "by"  and then loop from i+2 till j-1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can I do it in df for whole column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression on the strings to match everything is in between "drinking a" and "by"

```
(?<=drinking a)(.*)(?=by)
```

This should do the trick, you can try it on an online regex verifier.
For a reference on why this regex works: [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958785/text-analysis-python#70958882)

Answer (score 0):

using regexps

```
import re

lst = ['i am drinking a one beer', 'while my friend is drinking an other beer']

for item in lst:
    match = re.search('drinking\s+an?\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)', item, re.I)
    if match:
        print ('[{1}, {0}]'.format(match.group(1),match.group(2)))
```

output

```
[beer, one]
[beer, other]
```